# Overriding standard object view page with Visualforce breaks the Mini Console view in Agent Console

Tags: visualforce, console

Our reps use the Agent Console to view their Opportunities and we have the related Account record display in the Mini Console view for each one.  The relationship field that it's using is 'Account Name'.  Works great.

When I override the Opportunity view with a Visualforce page that uses the standard controller and simply displays the Opportunity detail, the Agent Console is no longer displaying the related Account record in the Mini Console view.

Any thoughts on how I can improve the VF page so the Mini Console view displays correctly?

VF page:

```
  <apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:detail id="detail" inlineEdit="true" relatedList="true" relatedListHover="true" subject="{!opportunity.Id}" title="true"/>
  </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's exactly supported in the console.

> "If your organization uses the Console tab, overrides for the Edit and View buttons for an object do not affect the Edit and View buttons in the mini page layouts. Pages that display due to overrides display in the console without the header or sidebar."

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_override_considerations.htm&language=en_US